# Does a function like this exist? void str_realloc_and_concat(char *str, const char *format, ...)

Tags: c, printf, realloc

I'm wondering if such a function exists:

```
void str_realloc_and_concat(char *str, const char *format, ...)
```

This function would take a char *str (allocated or NULL), and append to it *format.
I'm looking for something like a sprintf with realocation, strcpy and concatenation.

Does it exist or do I have to code it? Thanks for your inputs.

**Update**
The library has to be used on a embedded device so I don't want to use GNU extensions, since I'm not sure I'll have them.

Comment: It would append `str` to `format`? Why not the other way around?

Comment: It will exist if you write it.

Comment: I don't think it exists. The only string function that performs allocation that I can think of is `strdup`. The problem with *reallocation* is that you don't know whether `str` actually points to dynamically allocated memory or not. The function can never tell. So at best you can make a **copy**.

Comment: [talloc_asprintf_append_buffer](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/group__talloc__string.html#ga2b2413835aa49f303755f03fcdbf71ff) , part of the talloc library. Though, going down that path, you're best off using talloc for all your memory allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with this. Hope it will help.

```
/**
 * Reallocate a string and concatenate it with a formatted string.
 * The src string has to be allocated by malloc/calloc.
 * @param src Pointer to the original string
 * @param format Format string
 * @param ... Arguments that are to be formatted
 */
char *strcatf(char *src, const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list ap, cp;
  int format_length;
  size_t translation_length;
  char *dest;

  if (NULL == src) {
    return NULL;
  }

  va_start(ap, format);
  va_copy(cp, ap);

  translation_length = strlen(src);
  format_length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, cp);
  if ((dest = realloc(src, (translation_length + format_length + 1) * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
    free(src);
  } else {
    vsprintf(&(dest)[translation_length], format, ap);
  }
  va_end(ap);
  va_end(cp);
  return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of such a function. To my knowledge the standard C library does not contain a function such as the one you are looking for. Notice that I would recommend to pass the target string as a double pointer, since realloc may change the pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *prefix = "Hello";

void str_realloc_and_concat(char **str, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int i, n;
    char *s;

    n = strlen(*str);
    va_start(ap, format);
    i = vasprintf(&s, format, ap);
    *str = (char *)(realloc(*str, n + i + 1));
    if (*str != NULL)
        strncpy(&(*str)[n], s, i);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    char *s = (char *)(malloc(strlen(prefix)));
    strncpy(s, prefix, strlen(prefix));
    str_realloc_and_concat(&s, " %s", "world!");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bad things happen if `realloc` fails.

Comment: Thanks, looks great, and I learnt something about the va_list usage. I'll try to find a way not to use vasprintf.

Comment: If you don't want to use `vasprintf`, you can use snprintf twice instead -- the first time to find out what length of string you need to allocate.

Comment: Oh, that's a good comment! I was missing a function the calculates how long a printf output would be, but calling snprintf twice is clever!

Comment: Indeed @kaizer.se it's what I have done but I used vsprintf instead since I already have a va_list and no knowledge of the n size value.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have the realloc part, but it does allocate. GNU libc's `asprintf` is like `sprintf` but allocates the result (to be big enough).

```
char *res = NULL;
const char *str = "other string";
int ret = asprintf(&res, "Hi %d %s\n", 2, str);
```

Concatenation is just a special case of using the format string.. if I understand correctly.

Comment: Your solution is probably nicer than mine. I guess the realloc will mostly create a new pointer anyway, so I would also go with asprintf only...

Comment: It's a GNU extension and since this code will be used in embedded system I won't take the risk.